# MERN app with React Router works fine locally and on Heroku but not on ECS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router, amazon-ecs

My MERN app works fine locally and on Heroku but not on AWS ECS. I've deployed my app on AWS ECS and I get the following React Router error in the console in Google Chrome when I enter my AWS ELB (load balancer) domain name.

```
react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error
    at y (router.ts:5:20)
    at A (components.tsx:147:3)
    at El (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Su (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at os (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at as (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at k (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
di @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:189
Ao @ react-dom.production.min.js:144
wu @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
bu @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
yu @ react-dom.production.min.js:259
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:283
xs @ react-dom.production.min.js:281
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
k @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
O @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
router.ts:5 Uncaught Error
    at y (router.ts:5:20)
    at A (components.tsx:147:3)
    at El (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Su (react-dom.production.min.js:290:337)
    at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at os (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
    at as (react-dom.production.min.js:268:429)
    at k (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
y @ router.ts:5
A @ components.tsx:147
El @ react-dom.production.min.js:167
Su @ react-dom.production.min.js:290
bs @ react-dom.production.min.js:280
gs @ react-dom.production.min.js:280
vs @ react-dom.production.min.js:280
os @ react-dom.production.min.js:271
as @ react-dom.production.min.js:268
k @ scheduler.production.min.js:13
O @ scheduler.production.min.js:14
```

Also, when I enter in my actual domain name (which was purchased on Porkbun), it says that no website has been registered on this domain name even though my domain name is an alias to my AWS ELB domain name, but I'm guessing that's because the ELB domain name can't re-alias back to the actual domain name because of errors.

Can anyone properly diagnose my error(s)? What do I need to fix?

Comment: "Can anyone properly diagnose my error(s)?" No, not really without the original source code you are running. See [mcve]. Also, check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) if there is anything you need to configure differently for deploying your app on AWS.

Comment: My code is at https://github.com/arajni3/online_shopping_app. I also do not see anything I need to configure differently for AWS on the CRA link.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why. For some reason, my EC2 container is using old code that uses a Route component in my App.js that is not wrapped inside of a Routes component.

Comment: If your own answer has resolved your question, please make it as "Answered".